# Disable HDMI audio on tablet when using wired headset

Tags: android, hdmi, android-audiomanager

How can I disable HDMI audio output on tablet when using wired headset.
I would try

```
mgr = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mgr.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
```

and

```
mgr = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mgr.setParameters("audio_devices_out_active=AUDIO_CODEC");
```

It didn't work :'(

Answer (score 0):

Try with this permission in your manifest.

android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS.